# How many pages does the page table require?

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory

I have found this exercise on the Internet but I´m having problems with sections 4 and 5, because I don´t understand where do the solutions appear from.

**Example: Mapping VAs to PAs**

**Suppose**
 - Virtual memory of 2^32 bytes
 - Physical memory of 2^24 bytes
 - Page size is 2^10 (1K) bytes

---

**1. How many pages can be stored in physical memory at once?**

2^(24-10) = 2^14

**2. How many entries are ther in the page table?**

2^22

**3. How many bits are necessary per entry in the page table? (Assume each entry has PPN, residentbit, dirty bit)**

16

**4. How many pages does the table require?**

2^23 bytes = 2^13 pages

**5. What is the largest fraction of VM that might be resident?**

1/(2^8)

**6. A portion of the page table is given to the left. What is the physical address for virtual address 0x1804?**

VPN = 6 --> PPN = 2 --> PA = 0x804

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\text{VPN} & \text{D} & \text{R} & \text{PPN} \\ \hline
\text{0} & 0 & 0 & 7 \\ \hline
\text{1} & 1 & 1 & 9 \\ \hline
\text{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\text{5} & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{6} & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{7} & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ \hline
\text{8} & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{...} & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Could you help me with this two exercises?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: There are many numbers here (at least 9 of them). Please ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some of the answers seem incorrect to me.

**3] Number of bits required for a page table entry.**

Page table Entry=>   R==D==PPN

R ==>1bit

D ==>1bit

Number of frames =2^14 ==>14 bits

Number of bits in a page table entry= 1+1+14=16

**4] Number of pages required by page table**

As the page table itself will be stored in main memory it will require some pages.

Amount of memory required for page table =size of an entry * Number of entries

```
                                     =16 bits * 2^22

                                     =67108864 bits =8388608 bytes

                                     =8192= 2^13 pages (: 1 page=1024 bytes)
```

**5] What is the largest fraction of virtual memory resident:**

i.e. the amount of virtual memory that can reside in RAM.

i.e Total Physical memory / Total Virtual memory

```
                                     =2^24 /2^32

                                     =1 / 2^8

                                     =0.39% of virtual memory can be in RAM ant an instant of time.
```

Please go through [Virtual memory from Charles C. Lin.](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Memory/virtual.html)

I hope this may help....

Comment: After rethinking section 3 a while I think it is correct, since we can use the virtual page number as an index (it doesn´t necessarily have to be included in the page table). So instead of 38 bits I would use the first result of 16 bits both in section 3 and 4. And now I understand section 5!

Comment: Bingo!!! I have updated my post accordingly.Thanks...